# Как отобразить текст в Label в нижнем индексе

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю шаблон для отчета в QtRPT 2.0.0.Необходимо отобразить текст в виде нижнего индекса аналогично `<sub>`(Как можно было делать в FastReport,это то что Builder).Как это можно прописать в Label'e?

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь `UNICODE-Таблицей` Например, для верхнего индекса двойки (квадратные единицы) там используется код `U+00B2`А подстрочная единичка кодируется как  `U+2081` Если вам нужно отобразить  текст, скажем символов из десяти (телефон, имя), то это вполне подойдет.

```
   // GCC
   std::cout << //"код Символа из таблицы или сам символ";
   // Windows
    wcout << L //" код символа из таблицы или сам символ";
```

Вывести символ по коду  проще, если использовать С++11

```
const char *s  = u8"\u2081";
cout << s << endl;
```

Для Label сохраняем наши символы и пишем:

```
 QString str = s; //s1+ s2+ s3 
 QLabel *l = new QLabel (this);
 l->setText(str);
```

А если Вам необходимо отобразить текст большего размера, то тут уже нужно пользоваться сторонними библиотеками.